# python re.compile and split with ÆØÅ charcters

Tags: python, regex, split, python-2.x

I am very new in Python. 
I do have a file with a list of words. They contain Danish letters (ÆØÅ) but the re.compile do not understand theses characters. The function split the words by each ÆØÅ. The text are downloade from Twitter and Facebook and do not always contain only letters.

```
text = "Rød grød med fløde.... !! :)"
pattern_split = re.compile(r"\W+")
words = pattern_split.split(text.lower())
words = ['r', 'd', 'gr', 'd', 'med', 'fl', 'de']
```

The right result should be

```
    words = ['rød', 'grød', 'med', 'fløde']
```

How do I get the right result?

Full code

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import math, re, sys, os
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

# AFINN-111 is as of June 2011 the most recent version of AFINN
#filenameAFINN = 'AFINN/AFINN-111.txt'

# Get location of file
__location__ = os.path.realpath(
    os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))


filenameAFINN = __location__ + '/AFINN/AFINN-111DK.txt'
afinn = dict(map(lambda (w, s): (w, int(s)), [ 
            ws.strip().split('\t') for ws in open(filenameAFINN) ]))

# Word splitter pattern
pattern_split = re.compile(r"\W+")
#pattern_split = re.compile('[ .,:();!?]+')

def sentiment(text):
    print(text)
    words = pattern_split.split(text.lower().strip())
    print(words)
    sentiments = map(lambda word: afinn.get(word, 0), words)
    if sentiments:
        sentiment = float(sum(sentiments))/math.sqrt(len(sentiments))

    else:
        sentiment = 0
    return sentiment


# Print result
text = "ånd ånd med fløde... :)asd "
id = 999
split = "###"
print("%6.2f%s%s%s%s" % (sentiment(text), split, id, split, text))
```

Comment: You really want to learn about Unicode, encoding and decoding, then use `re.UNICODE` to switch on unicode support in regular expressions. See the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), and [Joel on Software on Unicode](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: (Works in Python 3 as written, so I added Python 2 tag)

Comment: @Wooble: exactly, because in Py3 the example string is Unicode and so is the regular expression.

Comment: When changing to Python 3.3 i get a compile error in "lamdba" 
afinn = dict(map(lambda (w, s): (w, int(s)), [ 
            ws.strip().split('\t') for ws in open(filenameAFINN) ]))

Comment: @boje: Python 3 has restrictions on using tuples in parameters (not allowed).

Comment: I added the full code. Because of my lack of Python knowledge are you (@MartijnPieters)able to write it so it would work in Python 3.3?

Comment: What encoding is the `AFINN` file in, UTF8?

Comment: Yes, UTF8.. I file with 3000 different danish words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reworking your script to use best practices:

```
import csv
import math
import os
import re

LOCATION = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
afinn_filename = os.path.join(LOCATION, '/AFINN/AFINN-111DK.txt')

pattern_split = re.compile(r"\W+")

with open(afinn_filename, encoding='utf8', newline='') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    afinn = {key: int(score) for key, score in reader}


def sentiment(text):
    words = pattern_split.split(text.lower().strip())
    if not words:
        return 0
    sentiments = [afinn.get(word, 0) for word in words]
    return sum(sentiments) / math.sqrt(len(sentiments))


# Print result
text = "ånd ånd med fløde... :)asd "
id = 999
split = "###"
print('{sentiment:6.2f}{split}{id}{split}{text}'.format(
    sentiment=sentiment(text), id=id, split=split, text=text))
```

Running this with Python 3 means that `text` is a Unicode object and that the regular expression is interpreted with the `re.UNICODE` set.

In Python 2, you'd use:

```
text = u"ånd ånd med fløde... :)asd "
```

(note the leading `u` prefix on the string) and

```
pattern_split = re.compile(ur"\W+", re.UNICODE)
```

Your AFINN file would be read as CSV still, but decoding the `key` from UTF8 after the fact, with:

```
with open(afinn_filename, 'rb') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    afinn = {key.decode('utf8'): int(score) for key, score in reader}
```

Comment: Thx. There any many error in you example, so i used your tip for Python 2. The only thing you where missing was this small code: codecs.open(filenameAFINN, "r", "utf-8")

Comment: @boje: no, I opened the file in binary mode, *then* decode from UTF-8, per word. Without an input file it is harder to test the code, it was written off the cuff. I'll take a look to see what can be fixed.

Comment: @boje: There, silly syntax errors cleaned up, sorry about those.

Answer (score 0):

I like to point to my `afinn` Python package which should work with international character sets, including the Danish one, and (some versions of) Python 2 and 3. There is an English and Danish word list. I will probably solve your problem.

Here Python 2.7 or Python 3.4:

```
>>> from afinn import Afinn
>>> afinn = Afinn(language='da', emoticons=True)
>>> afinn.score(u"ånd ånd med fløde... :)asd ")
4.0
>>> afinn.score('Hvis ikke det er det mest afskyelige flueknepperi...')
-6.0
```

You can get the library here:

https://github.com/fnielsen/afinn

or at the Python Package Index for `pip install afinn`