# Python regex with ØÆÅ letters

Tags: python, regex, encoding, python-2.x

I am new at Python so this may seem to be very easy. I am trying to remove all **#**, numbers and if the same letter is repeated more then two times in a row, I need to change it to only two letters. This work perfectly but not with ØÆÅ.

*Any ideas how this can be done with ØÆÅ letters?*

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import math, re, sys, os, codecs
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
text = "ån9d ånd ååååånd d9d flllllløde... :)asd "

# Remove anything other than digits
text = re.sub(r'#', "", text)
text = re.sub(r"\d", "", text)
text = re.sub(r'(\w)\1+', r'\1\1', text)
print "Phone Num : "+ text
```

The result I get now is:

```
Phone Num : ånd ånd ååååånd dd flløde... :)asd
```

What I want is:

```
Phone Num : ånd ånd åånd dd flløde... :)asd
```

Comment: We covered this before, didn't we? Use Unicode, not byte strings.

Comment: From my [answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549161/python-re-compile-and-split-with-charcters/16549766#16549766): *In Python 2, you'd use [unicode string example], note the leading u prefix on the string* and *[regular expression with the re.UNICODE set]*.

Comment: Hi @MartijnPieters, by looking into you comments a try some thing i did find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to work with Unicode values, not with byte strings. UTF-8 encoded `å` is *two* bytes, and a regular expression matching `\w` *only* matches ascii letters, digits and underscores when operating in the default non-Unicode-aware mode.

From the [`re` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) on `\w`:

> When the `LOCALE` and `UNICODE` flags are not specified, matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. With `LOCALE`, it will match the set `[0-9_]` plus whatever characters are defined as alphanumeric for the current locale. If `UNICODE` is set, this will match the characters `[0-9_]` plus whatever is classified as alphanumeric in the Unicode character properties database.

Unfortunately, even when you switch to properly using Unicode values (using a unicode `u''` literal or by decoding your source data to unicode values), using a Unicode regular expression (`re.sub(ur'...')`) and using the `re.UNICODE` flag to switch `\w` to match Unicode alphanumeric characters, the Python `re` module has limited support for Unicode matching still:

```
>>> print re.sub(ur'(\w)\1+', r'\1\1', text, re.UNICODE)
ånd ånd ååååånd dd flløde... :)asd
```

because `å` is not being recognized as alphanumeric:

```
>>> print re.sub(ur'\w', '', text, re.UNICODE)
å å ååååå  ø... :)
```

The solution is to use the external [`regex` library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) which is a version of the `re` library that adds proper full Unicode support:

```
>>> import regex
>>> print regex.sub(ur'(\w)\1+', r'\1\1', text, re.UNICODE)
ånd ånd åånd dd flløde... :)asd
```

That module can do more than just recognize more alphanumeric characters in Unicode values, see the linked package page for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
text = u"ån9d ånd åååååååånd d9d flllllløde... :)asd "
```

and

```
text = re.sub(r'(\w)\1+', r'\1\1', text)
```

**COMPELTE SOLUTION**

```
import math, re, sys, os, codecs
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
text = u"ån9d ånd åååååååånd d9d flllllløde... :)asd "

# Remove anything other than digits
text = re.sub(r'#', "", text)
text = re.sub(r"\d", "", text)
text = re.sub(r'(\w)\1+', r'\1\1', text)
text = re.sub(r'(\W)\1+', r'\1\1', text)
print "1: "+ text
```

Print:

```
1: ånd ånd åånd dd flløde.. :)asd
```

Comment: Also an option; note that you are now changing the `...` to `..` as well, but that may be fine for your needs.